# How to disable Alt+F hotkey in gnome as it messes up with application spesific hotkeys

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, libreoffice

After upgrading to 21.10 my LibreOffice writer shortcut for adding footnotes (Ctrl+Alt+F) stopped working. This is because Alt+F  opens File menu from the toolbar a cross all apps. How to change this fuction to Alt Gr or some other key? Already searched related shortcut from Keyboard settings but didn't find this option.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear, and correct typos. "shortcut Ctrl+Alt+F stopped working as Alt+F opens File menu from the toolbar" : it is unclear what the issue is here. Alt+F is *supposed* to open the File menu.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F is supposed to add a footnote on Writer, this is however trumped by a gnome shortcut Alt+F which opens File menu from the toolbar of any program. Obviously this is not working as suspected.